# NodeJS Post error, no form action

Tags: html, node.js, post, http-post

[Code screenshot. Right side Html, left side NodeJS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jS0j9.png)

I'm trying to make a simple post request but nothing happens when I click the 'Submit' button. Is there a way to fix this or is there another way to make a post call from within my onclick listener in my script file?

Comment: Put a [mcve] in the question itself. Don't link to a low contrast picture of text.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a submit button. `type="button"` has no default effect and needs JavaScript to do anything.

Submit buttons are `type="submit"` (which is the default).